# C: Large String input --> Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

My Problem is, that this code just works with tiny input-strings

The code should check if a input is an Palindrom. And there are two options, i implement them in extra functions (this error also appers, when i comment the functions out)

for example:
input "otto" - is okay
"reliefpfeiler" - is okay
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --> segmentation fault

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char* str;
   int erg;
   int c;
   char stroriginall[50];

   fgets(str,50,stdin);
   str[strlen(str)-1]='\0'; 

   if(strlen(str)>40)
   {
      printf("%s: Error, input must <=40!",argv[0]);
      return 1;
   }

   strcpy(stroriginall,str);

   while ((c=getopt(argc, argv, "si")) != -1)
   {
      switch(c)
      {
      case 's':
         str=removeSpaces(str);
         break;
      case 'i':
         toLowerCase(str);
         break;
      }
   }

   erg=checkPalindrom(str);

   if(erg==0)
   {
      printf("%s ist ein Palindrom\n",stroriginall);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("%s ist kein Palindrom\n",stroriginall);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

i hope anybody can help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your problems is that `str` is just a pointer (uninitialised for that matter) and you haven't allocated any memory for it. See:

```
char* str;
int erg;
int c;
char stroriginall[50];

fgets(str,50,stdin);
```

Change `char* str` to `char str[50]`. That call to `fgets` stores 50 `char`s into the buffer pointer to by `str`, there's no memory allocated for `str` so you'll segfault.

We also don't have the definition to the functions your calling where there could be plenty more problems.

You should also enable all of the warnings on your compiler so these problems are pointed out to you at compile time (if it didn't already do so).

Comment: thank you - but i cant understand why it has worked with small input?

Comment: @user1030620 I'm surprised it worked at all, the behaviour is completely *undefined*.